# Json encode error from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have done a little research on the following error `Warning: [json] (php_json_encode) type is unsupported, encoded as null`but have not found much in the way of answers?

I am trying to encode the result of a mysql query. Not sure what info I can provide.. but when I echo the results of the mysql data using

$data = json_encode($result);

echo $data;

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $content[] = $info;
            }

$count = count($content);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

        echo $content[$i]['Name'];

    }
```

every thing shows as normal. Any help would be great.

Comment: so if everything is normal, what is the problem

Comment: Show how you use `json_encode()`. What's your strings encoding?

Comment: @ibu the echo of the data not encoded shows correctly so I know it is returning data.

Comment: @zerkms I added the json_encode before the loop. see edit.

Comment: @Denoteone: have you tried to see what's inside `$result` with `var_dump($result);`? You'll be amazed ;-)

Comment: @serkms So what you are saying is what I am passing to the encode is not correct. Do I need to parse the result into an array first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$result=array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    $result[]=$content[$i]['Name'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks I see what I was doing I need to get the query result into an array first before encoding.

Comment: @Denoteone: I'd even say - you need to fetch result at first, becayse there is nothing but just a resource reference in the `$result` variable in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array` will return an array with both numeric and non-numeric values. That's fine for PHP, but it doesn't really play as well in other formats and it could very well be the cause of the issue. Have you tried `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

### BIG EDIT

Just noticed your code above. You have :

```
$data = json_encode($result);

echo $data;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

That won't work. $result is a resource data type. It can't be serialized into something which can be read by json_encode. You have to create an array of its contents first and serialize that. Just making sure you know.